# Proving a little tough trigonometric identity

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

Show that $$\frac{1+\sin A}{\cos A}+\frac{\cos B}{1-\sin B}=\frac{2\sin A-2\sin B}{\sin(A-B)+\cos A-\cos B}$$ How do I get the $A-B$ term in the denominator? Is RHS to LHS easier? Thanks.

Comment: **hint**

try multiplying LHS by RHS/RHS
e.g.
$$LHS = LHS\cdot\frac{RHS}{RHS}=\frac{LHS}{RHS}\cdot RHS=\dots=1\cdot RHS=RHS$$

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the following:
$\sin(A - B) = \sin(A) \cos(B) - \cos(A) \sin(B)$

Comment: Yeah, I know that but then isn't the denominator quite bad???

Answer (score 0):

Write

$$\frac{1+\sin A}{\cos A}=\frac{\cos A}{1-\sin A}$$

Then,

$$\frac{1+\sin A}{\cos A}+\frac{\cos B}{1-\sin B}=\frac{\cos A}{1-\sin A}+\frac{\cos B}{1-\sin B}=\frac{(\cos A+\cos B)+\sin(A-B)}{(1-\sin A)(1-\sin B)}$$

Multiply the right-hand side by $1=\frac{(\cos A-\cos B)+\sin(A-B)}{(\cos A-\cos B)+\sin(A-B)}$ and simplify.  It's messy, but doable.

Answer (score 0):

First, notice that
$$
\frac{1 + \sin A}{\cos A} = \frac{\cos A}{1 - \sin A}
$$
Next, regroup the denomitator as
$$
\sin(A - B) + \cos A - \cos B = \cos A(1 - \sin B) - \cos B(1 - \sin A)
$$
The right hand side becomes
$$
2\frac{\sin A - \sin B}{\cos A(1 - \sin B) - \cos B(1 - \sin A)} = 
2\frac{\frac{\tan A}{\cos B} - \frac{\tan B}{\cos A}}{\frac{1 - \sin B}{\cos B} - \frac{1 - \sin A}{\cos A}}.
$$
Multiplying both sides with ${\frac{1 - \sin B}{\cos B} - \frac{1 - \sin A}{\cos A}}$ we get
$$
\left(\frac{1 + \sin A}{\cos A} + 
\frac{1 + \sin B}{\cos B}\right) 
\left(\frac{1 - \sin B}{\cos B} - \frac{1 - \sin A}{\cos A}\right)
=
2\left(\frac{\tan A}{\cos B} - \frac{\tan B}{\cos A}\right)
$$
Expanding the left side gives
$$
\left(\frac{1 + \sin A}{\cos A} + 
\frac{1 + \sin B}{\cos B}\right) 
\left(\frac{1 - \sin B}{\cos B} - \frac{1 - \sin A}{\cos A}\right) = \\ =
\frac{1-\sin^2 B}{\cos^2 B} - \frac{1-\sin^2 A}{\cos^2 A} 
+ \frac{(1+\sin A)(1-\sin B)-(1-\sin A)(1+\sin B)}{\cos A\cos B} = \\ =
\frac{2\sin A - 2\sin B}{\cos A\cos B} = 2\left(\frac{\tan A}{\cos B} - \frac{\tan B}{\cos A}\right). \qquad \blacksquare
$$